# RESTful make sure POST response was received

Tags: rest, restful-authentication

How can I make sure application got a response with a new pair of access and refresh tokens.

**My problem is:**

I send a request to to the server to refresh access token and therefore generate a new refresh token. Server generates a new pair of tokens. Sends a response to the application, however application never receives the response, because of a Timeout exception or other connection issues.

Later on user tries to use application again, but refresh token is incorrect, because it was already updated on the server side.

How can I make sure that response was received on application side from the server side?

Comment: Why not make the client handle the error? The client knows whether the request went well or not, enabling it to request again if needed.

Comment: The problem is server side already changed access and refresh token's pair, but the client side never received them. Therefore client can't use any of the restful methods. How can I handle something like this on a client side, except with a prompt to re-enter login credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution here would be to not expire the old refresh token, until the associated access token is used first. Alternatively, you can simply not expire the refresh token right away and keep it valid for a while longer.